# WCF can't find certificate for CurrentUser

Tags: azure, wcf, ssl-certificate

I have a WCF service that is telling me it can't find its certificate:

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria:
>   StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType
>   'FindByThumbprint', FindValue
>   'cf51e92041d0440a262df6a357f3f709f6f8d710'.

and the config specifies the certificate by the thumbprint

```
<serviceCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" 
     findValue="cf51e92041d0440a262df6a357f3f709f6f8d710" 
     x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
```

Using the powershell command `Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My` finds the certificate.  If I change the config file to specify **LocalMachine** the service starts correctly.

What is going on?  I suppose I could change the config file, however, when publishing my service to Azure then it can't find the uploaded certificate because that is looking in **CurrentUser**.  I know I could use different configs for different environments, but I don't want to blindly head down that path without understanding the "why" of things.

Comment: Ah, it turns out if I change the ApplicationPool user to my account (which has full permissions) it works.  Is there a way to grant ApplicationPoolIdentity access?  Yes, I know this isn't ideal but this will only be done for a few developer machines